# JAVA Programming Execute Multiple Times

Tags: java, runtime, execution, bubble-sort

I have written a BubbleSort program and it works great, gives me a good output and does its job sufficiently. But I am unable to make the program re-execute after sorting through once. I.e. the program completes a sort of 10000 unique numbers and outputs the time it takes and the amount of steps it took, but doesn't execute again, say for another 999 times after that?

In short, can anyone help me get my program to run through itself 1000 times so I am able to get an average of execution time?

Here is the code:

```
public class BubbleSort {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int BubArray[] = new int[] { #10000 unique values unsorted# };

      System.out.println("Array Before Bubble Sort");
      for (int a = 0; a < BubArray.length; a++) {
         System.out.print(BubArray[a] + " ");
      }

      double timeTaken = bubbleSortTimeTaken(BubArray);
      int itrs = bubbleSort(BubArray);
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("Array After Bubble Sort");
      System.out.println("Moves Taken for Sort : " + itrs + " moves.");
      System.out.println("Time Taken for Sort : " + timeTaken
            + " milliseconds.");
      for (int a = 0; a < BubArray.length; a++) {
         System.out.print(BubArray[a] + " ");
      }
   }

   private static int bubbleSort(int[] BubArray) {

      int z = BubArray.length;
      int temp = 0;

      int itrs = 0;

      for (int a = 0; a < z; a++) {
         for (int x = 1; x < (z - a); x++) {

            if (BubArray[x - 1] > BubArray[x]) {

               temp = BubArray[x - 1];
               BubArray[x - 1] = BubArray[x];
               BubArray[x] = temp;

            }

            itrs++;
         }
      }

      return itrs;
   }

   public static double bubbleSortTimeTaken(int[] BubArray) {
      long startTime = System.nanoTime();
      bubbleSort(BubArray);
      long timeTaken = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
      return timeTaken;
   }
}
```

and here are the results output (note it is limited to just one run):

```
Unsorted List : 
[13981, 6793, 2662, 733, 2850, 9581, 7744 .... ]
Sorted List with BubbleSort

Moves Taken to Sort : 1447551 Moves.
Time Taken to Sort : 1.2483121E7 Milliseconds.

[10, 11, 17, 24, 35, 53, 57, 60, 78, 89, 92 ... ]
```

Comment: what is the issue in extracting `main()` code in a new method and calling the same 1000 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited code...

```
public class BubbleSort {
    static double bestTime = 10000000, worstTime = 0;  //global variables
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int BubArray[] = new int[]{3,5,3,2,5,7,2,5,8};

    System.out.println("Array Before Bubble Sort");
    for(int a = 0; a < BubArray.length; a++){
    System.out.print(BubArray[a] + " ");

    }

  System.out.println("\n Entering Loop...");

  for(int i=0; i<1000;i++)
  {  
  bubbleSortTimeTaken(BubArray, i);
  }


        int itrs = bubbleSort(BubArray);
        System.out.println("");               
        System.out.println("Array After Bubble Sort");
        System.out.println("Moves Taken for Sort : " + itrs + " moves.");
        System.out.println("BestTime: " + bestTime + " WorstTime: " + worstTime);
        System.out.print("Sorted Array: \n");
            for(int a = 0; a < BubArray.length; a++){
                    System.out.print(BubArray[a] + " ");
            }
    }

 private static int bubbleSort(int[] BubArray) {

    int z = BubArray.length;
    int temp = 0;

    int itrs = 0;

    for(int a = 0; a < z; a++){
            for(int x=1; x < (z-a); x++){

                    if(BubArray[x-1] > BubArray[x]){

                            temp = BubArray[x-1];
                            BubArray[x-1] = BubArray[x];
                            BubArray[x] = temp;
                    }    

                    itrs++;
            }
    }

    return itrs;
}

public static void bubbleSortTimeTaken(int[] BubArray, int n) 
{

     long startTime = System.nanoTime();

     bubbleSort(BubArray);   

     double timeTaken = (System.nanoTime() - startTime)/1000000d;

     if(timeTaken > 0)
     {
         if(timeTaken > worstTime)
         {
             worstTime = timeTaken;
         }
         else if(timeTaken < bestTime)
         {
             bestTime = timeTaken;
         }

     }

     System.out.println("Loop number: "+n + " Time Taken: " + timeTaken);


}
}
```

Comment: Is there a way instead of BubArray = new int {array ints}; ... to say, call the BubArray again (999 times) and calculate each time ... so 1000 different amounts of "Time Taken" and "Moves Taken", does that make sense?

Comment: the value of BubArray is going to change everytime it enters the loop?
if yes, then how? randomly?

Comment: I mean the same 10000 unique values for each execution, but I need to calculate the average time for 1000 executions. "You can measure how long it takes to sort the data 1,000 times, then divide this time by 1,000 to get an average for running the sort once." . It's to plot on a graph to find Worst, Avg, Best Case.

Comment: and the code is printing out time in nanoseconds.. u need to divide by 10^6 to get time in millis

Comment: so.. u want to run the bubbleSort 1000 times and u need the exectution time for every time it runs and find the best and worst possible execution times right?

Comment: and i assume number of moves will remain the same since the bubbleSort array does not change.. Only thing required is time of execution for each of the 1000 times right?

Answer (score -1):

Move the method below

```
private static int bubbleSort(int[] BubArray)
```

in to some other class extending `Thread`. May be you can create new threads each time execution finishes. A static instance variable in root class can be used to hold the times.

Comment: Threading does not seem to be a requirement in the question. No need to add unnecessary complexity.